# Why does Dataflow erratically fail in Datastore access?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, app-engine-flexible

My simple Dataflow pipeline successfully copies multiple Kinds from one project's Datastore to another in most cases. But in certain Kinds (about 5% of them),  we always get these errors.

Dataflow retries 4-8 times with a delay of about 75 seconds, and then the pipeline fails.

How can I diagnose and resolve this?

EDIT: The answer includes: (1) there was a bug in the Datastore library used by Dataflow; after they fixed this bug, you can see the underlying cause and (2) the default batch size  for putting entities in this library is 500, which is also the max, and that goes over the 10 Mb limit of the Datastore API.

The (very simple) Pipeline looks like this:

```
Query.Builder qb = Query.newBuilder();
qb.addKindBuilder().setName(kindName);
Query query = qb.build();
Read dsRead = DatastoreIO.v1().read().withProjectId(inputProject).withQuery(query);
Write dsWrite = DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(outputProject);
PCollection<Entity> sourceEntities = pipeline.apply("read", dsRead);
Bound<Entity, Entity> entityFromSrcToTarget = ParDo.of(new EntityDoFn());/*Simple DoFn that copies Entities for insertion to target*/
PCollection<Entity> clonedEntities = sourceEntities.apply("clone-entity", entityFromSrcToTarget);
clonedEntities.apply("write-to-ds", dsWrite);
```

First stacktrace

```
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: I/O error, code=UNAVAILABLE at
com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:126) at
com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:95) at
com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:84) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.flushBatch(DatastoreV1.java:925) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.finishBundle(DatastoreV1.java:899) Caused by: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written at
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3500) at
com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:81) at
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981) at
com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:87) at
com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:84) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.flushBatch(DatastoreV1.java:925) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.finishBundle(DatastoreV1.java:899) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.finishBundle(DoFnRunnerBase.java:158) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.finishBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:196) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.finishBundle(ForwardingParDoFn.java:47) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:65) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:80) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:223) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also

```
(9908b474b1492772): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: I/O error, code=UNAVAILABLE at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:162) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:283) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:507) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.java:125) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:202) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:143) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:72) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:287) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:223) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173) at 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160) at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This looks like either throttling or overload on the Datastore side.  Could you provide a Job ID?

Comment: From the stack trace, the root cause is - `com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.finishBundle(DatastoreV1.java:899) Caused by: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written`. I found a similar bug at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/pull/1187, which was marked as fixed by adding a retry option. Are you using the latest version of the API?

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla I am using com.google.cloud.dataflow.google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all version 1.7.0 (From maven).

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla "which was marked as fixed by adding a retry option." How do I do that? But note also that Dataflow is retrying the Kind 4-8 times with a ~75 second gap between each retry.

Comment: @SamMcVeety Job ID 2016-10-20_06_37_36-1944046122903944603

Comment: @SamMcVeety The Dataflow is a simple Datastore backup: Read-then-write to another Datastore. Note that the same 5 out of 130 Kinds always fail as I rerun this, whether I run each Kind in a separate Pipeline or a number of Kinds  together in one Pipeline.  This suggests that the problem is not with simple overload or throttling. 

Clue: Running against a nonexistent Kind gives a similar error. But these Kinds *are* populated.  Also, these are not the largest Kinds. Maybe there is something problematic in the data of those Kinds? I think not, but I'd like to see a better error message if so.

Comment: I have reached out to the Datastore team to debug with them.

Comment: This appears to be a quota issue, that is being misrepresented by the error message.  Are you able to increase the quota for your project via the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/pricing?

Comment: @SamMcVeety It seems that it is probably not a quota issue. (What resource were you thinking of?). The Quota pages in the Console show that we are far below quota on all resources on both source and target projects. Also, these five Kinds consistently show this exception (I don't know if it's in read or write), while 120 other Kinds consistently succeed, even on repeat runs. (Also, we increased the maximum billable amount, but again, we are far below that in any case.)

Comment: @SamMcVeety Job Id 2016-10-25_04_43_59-5193766273039635775 failed today; it's the same Kind as 2016-10-21_00_31_14-11121776639025713355 last week. In contrast,  2016-10-25_04_44_26-17162760287352949364 succeeds with MUCH more data on repeat runs.

Comment: Apologies for the silence, working to get more information on this.

Comment: @SamMcVeety Thank you, looking forward to it.

Comment: Clue:

Workers give these log lines. From https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=738 I see that these are not necessarily an indication of a bug , but may be a clue.
Refused to split GroupingShuffleReader <unstarted in shuffle range [ShufflePosition(base64:AAAAAUc2ap9ADopGAP8AAQ), ShufflePositio n(base64:AAAAAYTO8b-ABxAA_wAB))> at ShufflePosition(base64:AAAAAUc2ap9ADopGAP8AAQ)
Proposing dynamic split of work unit tradeos-test1;2016-10-30_05_54_43-17884292562202311365;544242318678188737 at {"position":{"shufflePosition":"AAAAAUc2ap9ADopGAP8AAQ"}}

Comment: That last one is from job ID 2016-10-30_05_54_43-17884292562202311365

Comment: Along with the other error messages, I get DEADLINE_EXCEEDED.Still, it appears that the underlying cause is in the Datastore-write. 
"...RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: (zmq) RPC timed out when dataflow-bk-rfq-10300422-5cf4-harness-g6yd talking to tcp://bk-rfq-10300422-5cf4-harness-56aa:12345. Server unresponsive (ping error: status: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED). Also see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#tsg-rpc-timeout
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.BatchingShuffleEntry...

Comment: Trying Dataflow again a number of Kinds shows that this is worse on the biggest Kinds, in contrast to what I found earlier. Yet Dataflow is meant to handle exactly this sort of scalability. My Pipeline simply selects with Read, then copies the entity, changing its Key to suit the target project Writes; and chains these together

Comment: See body for core pipeline code

Comment: @JoshuaFox "insufficient data written" is actually masking the underlying exception that we aren't able to see and thus making it hard to debug this issue. (The masking issue is fixed in https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/pull/333 - yet to be merged). Working with Datastore team to see if this change can be merged and put into a new Datastore client release. Will provide an update tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I would guess that Datastore is having some sort of capacity issue. It will be good to know what.

Comment: FWIW, a simple "query and insert" using the gcloud-java-datastore 0.2.8 API -- without Dataflow  --  was successful with one of the Kinds that failed in the Dataflow Pipeline.

Comment: @JoshuaFox this is the 'cloud-eng-dev' project right? Can you also give a job_id for one in which writes to 'cloud-eng-dev' datastore succeeded? That might help compare with ones that are failing.

Comment: Nvm I found them. Looks like one of the jobs worked just fine. So for the failing jobs the requests never reached Datastore service. Looks like a client side issue. I am trying get this released,  github.com/google/google-http-java-client/pull/333  and hopefully we can try it out to get a clearer error message. In the mean time could you try removing the 'gcloud-java-datastore' from your dependency and repro the issue with 'simple pipeline that you posted? I want to make sure it is not a weird dependency issue that we are hitting.

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli I removed gcloud-java-datastore from the pom.xml and made sure it was not in the effective POM. I got basically the same results as before. Most Kinds can be copied (e.g. Job ID 2016-11-03_07_09_30-2657413290769640959), whether one per pipeline or several together in a pipeline (unioning the PCollections with *and*). Exactly the same 5 Kinds as before failed when copied each in their own pipeline (e.g.,
2016-11-03_07_10_46-3370186458561566357). However, when I ran the 5 Kinds together in a joint Pipeline, 4 *succeeded* and 1 failed (2016-11-03_06_54_04-7512693788272617823).

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Similarly, running without the gcloud-java-datastore dependency on the other project where some Kinds succeeded and some failed, the same error message still occurs. Job ID 2016-11-03_07_58_28-16985885300957305885

Comment: @JoshuaFox Trying to get hold of folks to get github.com/google/google-http-java-client/pull/333 merged. Will update once that is in, so that we could try getting better error messages when this issue occurs.

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Thanks, that will be useful. I'm guessing that as soon as we see the error message we'll home in quickly  on a solution.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: Release 3 different libraries would probably take more time. What i am going to do is to make a custom releases for these libraries and make a Dataflow release on my branch, which you could try out. Stay tuned.

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli thanks, that will be useful

Comment: @JoshuaFox: https://github.com/vikkyrk/DataflowJavaSDK/tree/http_fix is my dataflow branch that depends on the updated jars. Here is what you need to do, 1) Clone that repo/branch 2) ./jars/install.sh 3) mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true 4) Place your simple pipeline code in examples directory 5) mvn compile -pl examples -Dexec.mainClass=<fully qualified name to your simple pipeline> -Dexec.args="<your args>"

Comment: I followed your instructions. I had to adjust source/target to Java 1.8, since my code uses Java8 features, and also to add dependencies to the pom, but I tried to avoid adding any dependencies that clash with yours.

Are you sure that your instructions cause the class to run? Mavan succeeded in that last command you give, but apparently nothing was run. See the output here http://pastebin.com/Qsh0gzJX

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli  Or alternatively, please let me know how to use your library in my own project. Perhaps I can remove a certain dependency (which?) from my pom and put your compiled code in my classpath? Or add your source code to my source path?

Comment: @JoshuaFox there was a typo. It should be "mvn compile exec:java ...." . exec:java tells it to run.

Comment: Adding it to your project might be more involved. The reason I chose my branch is that both have access it for debugging

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Thank you. The failure is the same, as expected, but the first of the two stacktrace in the body of  the OP (starting UNAVAILABLE), provides more info than before.

See http://pastebin.com/rDswCdF2. 

The error concerns Protobuf. 

Otherwise, the stacktraces are the same *after* your change, Job 2016-11-12_09_47_29-9537593825735629484; compared to before *before* your change with all other aspects the same, Job 2016-11-11_04_52_16-7323696975109393597.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: That is a much useful error! The error seems to be related to a single HttpRequest being too large and it explains why you are seeing this on kinds with large entities. A single request is probably exceeded the Http PostBuffer size configured in the cloud. I will get back to you on how to configure it or if this could something be handled in the SDK.

Comment: In the meantime if you want to confirm this, you could try reducing the batch size here https://github.com/vikkyrk/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/http_fix/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/datastore/DatastoreV1.java#L189. Set it to 50 or 100 and see if this helps. (Make sure that you run mvn clean install after you make the change, for it to be picked up)

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Yes! That did it! 

In fact, I encountered "too-large" errors with a simple no-Dataflow implementation against  the Google Cloud API. When putting Entities in batches of 500 failed, I had my process retry the put, exponentially decreasing batch-size until the put succeeded. 

If we simply change DATASTORE_BATCH_UPDATE_LIMIT to 50, we will slow down the Dataflow implementation, right? And there's no guarantee that 50 is small enough. What's the best way to resolve that? (And I am also wondering: Why am I the only one encountering this "too-large" error?)

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Do you want to add an answer so I can "accept" it  -- or I can write that answer myself.

Comment: The two parts of the answer are (1) The need for a fix, available at Github, that exposes the error in the log; (2) the too-large batch puts, which can be made smaller by changing a static field.
The URL for those is https://github.com/vikkyrk/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/http_fix/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/datastore/DatastoreV1.java#L189

Comment: @JoshuaFox Filed a jira under Apache Beam (incubating) project https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-991. Feel free to track the progress there. I will add an answer once the issue is resolved.