# How can we prevent Google Cloud API from swallowing exceptions?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I sometimes get the following exception on put(). (Though in general, my code works fine.)

My  best guess is that Datastore internally encounters an indexing error (which there are [no tools for diagnosing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522528/)), but I am not sure because the error is swallowed with a Protobuf parsing problem.

[In another case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156400/why-does-dataflow-erratically-fail-in-datastore-access), a similar swallowing of exceptions, with Protobuf parsing message, was caused by a bug internal to Dataflow's own Datastore API, and the Dataflow team fixed that -- but here I am not using Dataflow at all.

How can I learn what is causing this?

Using Google Cloud API 0.28.

```
   ... at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.put(DatastoreImpl.java:340)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commitMutation(DatastoreImpl.java:380)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.commit(DatastoreImpl.java:386)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:244)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:179)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:387)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:390)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.commit(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:131)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:84)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:89)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:148)
    at com.google.rpc.Status.parseFrom(Status.java:323)
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseWithIOException(Lcom/google/protobuf/Parser;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a symptom of an older version of the `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java` artifact making it onto your classpath. The `GeneratedMessage.parseWithIOException` method was added in `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0`.

One approach for preventing that is adding a `dependencyManagement` section to your pom file:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Once the dependency issue is cleaned up, the client should be able to correctly parse `Status` protos and display the underlying error.

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick. The exception is indeed a "Index entries too large for entity" exception